# Comparing two dataframes using all.equal

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, similarity

I have two dataframes that contain the same columns. But for some data importing issues/differences in sources of data, the classes of the same columns across two dataframe may not be the same. I want to use all.equal to only check if the values in both dataframes are the same. If they are not the same, I want to know the row and column number where the difference lies. I don't want to know if the classes are different. How can I do it using all.equal?

Here is my output so far and I can't make much sense of it:

```
[1] "Component “ins_name”: 32 string mismatches"                                                                                   
 [2] "Component “reg_no”: Mean relative difference: 0.02519084"                                                                      
 [3] "Component “company_id”: 11 string mismatches"                                                                         
 [4] "Component “company_name”: 14 string mismatches"                                                                                 
 [5] "Component “rep_date”: Attributes: < Length mismatch: comparison on first 1 components >"                   
 [6] "Component “rep_date”: Attributes: < Component “class”: Lengths (1, 2) differ (string compare on first 1) >"
 [7] "Component “rep_date”: Attributes: < Component “class”: 1 string mismatch >"                                
 [8] "Component “rep_date”: target is Date, current is POSIXct"                                                  
 [9] "Component “au_date”: Attributes: < Length mismatch: comparison on first 1 components >"                    
[10] "Component “au_date”: Attributes: < Component “class”: Lengths (1, 2) differ (string compare on first 1) >" 
[11] "Component “au_date”: Attributes: < Component “class”: 1 string mismatch >"                                 
[12] "Component “au_date”: target is Date, current is POSIXct"                                                   
[13] "Component “industry”: 9 string mismatches"                                                                                    
[14] "Component “totalhours”: Mean relative difference: 0.1774153"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the original datasource csv, xlsx, or something else?  If it is xlsx, then you could use the `tidyxl` package which preserves the datatype of the original on a cell-by-cell basis.

Comment: Pick 1 data frame to be the master and convert the other data frames classes to the class of the master.